# Decoding single json object in corona

Tags: json, lua, coronasdk

I am trying to get a single object from parse.com through the following code:

```
tables = json.decode(event.response) 
nvote1[1] = tables.results[1].nvote
```

It works fine with the following network request (using Corona SDK.

```
network.request( baseUrl .. objectClass, "GET", networkNo,  params)
```

However, the decode function doesn't work with a single object request.

```
network.request( baseUrl .. objectClass .."/".. "f6POZnH987", "GET", networkNo,  params)
```

It seems to me that the decode function in Corona only works when the pattern is repeated as opposed when you have a single object. Does anyone know the fix around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply added the following characters and it works fine. It's surprising that Corona will have such a simple glitch.

```
tables = '{ "results": [ '..string.sub(event.response, 0,-2)..'] }'
```